# Infinite series over lattice of Gaussian integers

Tags: complex-analysis, integer-lattices, elliptic-functions

I'm trying to show that the following sum converges to $0$ over the lattice $L = \mathbb{Z}[i]$ of Gaussian integers:

$$ 140\times\sum_{\substack{l \in L \\ l\neq 0}} l^{-6} = 0. $$

I don't really know how to attack this, I haven't studied complex analysis yet. What I've noticed is that the sums over the pure real and imaginary parts cancel out as $i^{-6} = -1$. So, that leaves all the terms not on the imaginary or real axis to deal with.

Would anyone have hints on how to proceed?

Comment: First do it without the $140$....

Comment: $(il)^{-6}=-l^{-6}$